# Seo routes with ember serializer

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Im following the example emberjs guides

```
...
this.route('author', { path: '/author/:post_userName' });
...

App.PostsAuthorRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.Post.find({userName : params.userName});
  },

  serialize:function(model) {
    return { post_userName: model.get('userName')};
  }
});
```

Then here is the link to

```
Author {{#linkTo 'posts.author' post }} {{post.userName }} {{/linkTo}}
```

The fun is when I click on the link I get a routing error

```
Error while loading route: TypeError {}
Uncaught TypeError: Object [Object Object] has no method 'slice'
```

But when I reload the page, the full data appears.

How can I solve the routing error, really I don't understand why I get the error and is solved on reload the page

Here is the jsbin of a similar case.

http://jsbin.com/aZIXaYo/31/edit

Comment: What is the versions of ember.js, ember-data, jquery, handlebars? Did params.userName has some value? I think that the correct would be params.post_userName ...

Comment: DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.6 ember.js:361
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.4 ember.js:361
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.8.2

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the object you're passing to your `link-to`.  You're doing this :

```
Author {{#linkTo 'posts.author' post }} {{post.userName }} {{/linkTo}}
```

which passes, a `Post` to the `author` route.  Passing a model to `link-to` causes the `model` hook on the route to be skipped and the passed model is used instead.  When you hit reload, the `model` hook is executed and the model for `PostsAuthor` route is set to be a collection of `Post` objects, and then things work as expected.

To do things The Ember Way (TM), you'd want to have an `Author` model that was related to your `Post` model.  Then you'd have an `AuthorRoute` and `AuthorController` that `needs` a `PostsController`.  In your link you'd pass `post.author`, and then use the `setupController` hook to prime the collection for the `PostsController`.  Something like this:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  author : DS.belongsTo('post'),
  title  : DS.attr('string')
});

App.Author = DS.Model.extend({
  name : DS.attr('string'),
  userName : DS.attr('string')
});

App.AuthorRoute = DS.Route.extend({
  model : function(){ // not called when the author is passed in to #link-to
    return this.store.find('author',{userName : params.post_userName})
  },
  setupController : function(controller,model){
    this._super(controller,model);
    this.controllerFor('posts').set('content', this.store.find('post',{userName : model.userName}))
  }
});

App.AuthorController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs : ['posts']
});

App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
 sortProperties : ['name']
});
```

Then the template :

```
Author {{#linkTo 'posts.author' post.author }} {{post.author.name }} {{/linkTo}}
```

Comment: I dont understand for what is then the serialize, If I read the documentation is for make routes more frienly based on the current model. The adapter I user dont have model relations implemented so I cant use this solution :(. 

Is there a way to force the model hook on the route ??

Comment: What adapter are you using?  You're going to have an awfully tough time with Ember trying to do things without proper relationships.  I'd recommend switching to an adapter that supports them if at all possible.  The `serialize` hook is the inverse of `model`.  When you pass a live model to a route `serialize` is called to generate the URL params, and `model` is not called, since the route already has a model.  When the page reloads `model` is called since the route doesn't have a model yet, and `serialize` is skipped since the URL is already complete.